# Word 2010: Style Sets are missing

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

The style sets list is empty on my computer for all users. It was working fine a couple of days ago. I tried the "repair" command already but it didn't fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that seemed to fix this was a complete uninstall and reinstall.